# Where is the bitcoind executable on Windows 10?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, windows

I have installed bitcoin core 0.17.1 version windows 10 in my laptop.

I can see the following folders: bin (bitcoin-cli.exe, bitcon-qt.exe, bitcoin-tx.exe, test_bitcoin.exe), include (bitcoinconsensus.h), lib (libbitcoinconsensus-0.dll), share (man).

I cannot find daemon\bitcoind. 
My bitcoin server is already running and sync on testnet, but I cannot connect via rpc because I cannot find bitcoind.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It's at `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon`.

**NOTE:** On the [download page](https://bitcoin.org/en/download), make sure to choose **the installer**, not the **zip file**.

The first one:

[image]

Comment: Yes. In fact, I I installed at C:\Program Files\bitcoin-0.17.1. That is where I can find all folders (bin, include, bin, share). No deamon folder.

Comment: @SuzanaMaranhão See the updated answer please.